# download telerik binaries only

Tags: asp.net, dll, telerik

Is there a way to download only binaries instead of 1.2 GB of telerik Ajax which contain all the demos and etc?

Download path to complete thing is [here](http://www.telerik.com/download-trial-file.aspx?pid=561).

Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Register/Logon](https://www.telerik.com/account/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/account/default.aspx) with Trial account.

Go to Manage Products > Trial Downloads > Download Link> Choose "Using the HOTFIX (DLLs and Scripts/Skins only)"

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-using-hotfix.html

> **Note**:
>   If you are installing the Telerik products for the first time, we
>   recommend that you download the complete package (MSI or ZIP file).

Comment: Possibly this is my solution. Let me download it and verify.

Comment: Does all the controls come under 1 Telerik.Web.UI.dll?

Answer (score 0):

I know you have the option to just download the binaries once you've purchased the controls, but I don't think that option is available with the trial version.